# c++ default statement will be printed multiple times

Tags: c++, char

```
void menu() {
    char mode = ' ';
    cout << "Gebe einen Modus an. 1 Addition, 2 Subtraktion, 3 Multiplikation, 4 Division: ";
    cin >> mode;
    switch (mode) {
    case '1':
        addition();
        break;
    case '2':
        subtraktion();
        break;
    case '3':
        multiplikation();
        break;
    case '4':
        division();
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Ungueltige Eingabe, versuch es nochmal\n";
        menu();
        break;

    }
}
```

Hey! I have the problem, that If I input more than one character, which are not valid, the default statement will be executed just as often as the length of my input. But shouldnt It be like that:
If I input to a char more than one letter, everything after the letter will be cut off, since a char can only save one character. So why does it get executed multiple times? Could anyone explain this, detailed? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: `default: menu();` -- Use proper loop constructs, not this.  All you're doing is unnecessarily creating recursion, decreasing the stack space.  All someone has to do is write a script that presses the `5` key a few thousand times, and then boom.

Comment: Off-topic, but important: The German imperative of "geben" is "gib". -> "Gib einen Modus an."

Comment: "shouldn't it be like that" -- no. Please take a look at e.g. cppreference.com, where you will find the descriptions of those operations. It may be hard to read, but the info is there. Also, browse what other tools you have, maybe one of them fits your requirements.

Comment: Say you enter `abcd`. The input stream now contains four characters. `cin >> mode` reads the first one: `mode` is now set to `a`, with `bcd` still in the stream. The switch goes to `default` case, calls `menu` again, which runs `cin >> mode` again. This reads the next character in the stream: `mode` is set to `b`, with `cd` still in the stream. Lather, rinse, repeat.